# How do you make a Google Chat Space accessible to everyone in an organization?

Tags: google-chat

I'm trying to create some spaces for my team like "Lunch" and "Happy Hour" so they can coordinate those things and post relevant topics. However, when I create the space, it does not appear when they go to the + and *Browse Spaces*. I would rather have this be an opt-in process than an opt-out one.

How can I create a space that is then viewable in the *Browse Spaces* window?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please read https://support.google.com/chat/answer/7653881?hl=en. If you need further help please add more details.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for the comment. That article does not address the issue. Also the question is pretty self-explanatory already: why do created spaces not show up in the Browse Spaces menu for others.